# How to set the setter for variables with other types of input in swift Language for ios?

Tags: ios, swift

The title is a little ambiguous, but I show my question by below example. Suppose I would like to define a variable that shows the value in certain index of array. I would like to realize that in setter. How to do that? I tried the below code, but it is wrong and cannot be compiled. It is obvious that index cannot be defined in setter, but are there any other way to realize that in setter?

```
var myArray = ["a", "b", "c"]
var myValue: String?{
get{}
set(var index: Int){self.myValue = myArray.objectAtIndex(index)}
}
var test: String? = myValue(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding what you're trying to do here, but I think you're going about this in the wrong way. If you wanted the variable to just return the object at a certain index in the array, then that is something that you would do from the getter. Additionally, since it looks like you want to pass a value in to determine what the output is, then you should probably just use a function. Example:

```
var myArray = ["a", "b", "c"]

func myValue(index: Int) -> String? {
    if index < myArray.count {
        return myArray[index]
    }

    return nil
}

var test = myValue(1)
```

Comment: Your solution is the main way I did it before, but I am now learning the setter/getter of swift, so just wondering whether there is a way to realize that without write a new function?

Comment: @Peterxwl Not that I'm aware of. At least, not without having to make the variables type AnyObject for the weird IO, and using an additional variable to store the index.